# Are there high chances of getting visa refusal in UK for misinformation?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications, work, minors

I applied for a UK work visa recently and when filling the form I answered “no” with respect to have you ever been refused visa to the UK. However upon discussion with my parents I was informed I was refused a visiting visa as a minor (14 years) 12 years ago. Do I need to update my application as I am yet to do my biometrics.

Comment: I presume your entire family was refused, not just you?

Comment: It was just my older brother and I, my parents and younger sister were granted visas.

Comment: If you’ve submitted the application and paid the fee, AFAIK there is no easy way to update it even if you’ve not yet given biometrics. You’ll need to contact UKVI https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/prepare-your-application

Comment: Do not worry. You were minor, and you didn't complete the form. It seems good faith (and you were not responsible at the time, as minor). You cannot be blamed (by UK foreign office) on something you cannot be blamed by laws

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi deception is deception, regardless of whether the subject of the deception occurred when the applicant was a minor.  If the Home Office thinks the current application is deceptive, it will be refused.  It is of utmost importance for the applicant to tell the Home Office immediately.  Otherwise the Home Office may conclude that the application is deceptive.  Michael is definitely right to be worried.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi It’s not really a question of blame, IMHO. UKVI could well conclude that the OP did not truthfully answer the question about any previous refusals. It would be much better, IMHO, to withdraw this application and submit another with the correct information, rather than risk a refusal on a work visa application that could prove very difficult/costly/time-consuming to overcome.

Comment: @phoog: Good faith. it is basic of laws. It is not required that you know all things, and it was un UK or US forms that it is explicitly written "In good faith I confirm..."? The OP wrote the application as good/truthfully as he could. It is not the first time I find hear excess zeal about laws: it is never black or white. Laws is never absolute, it apply always on real cases, looking all things. Tell me where in UK laws where a person could be accused about errors made when he was minor, and the error was committed by others. US is much more explicit: all things are reset, also long overstay.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi but UK visa officers are well known for making unreasonable findings of deception, and the consequences of such a finding include a *ten-year ban.*  Of course the moral and ethical thing for the Home Office to do is not to hold this against the applicant, but in the last several years the Home Office has shown every inclination to act in an *immoral* and *unethical* manner towards visa applicants.  Advising to someone in this position "not to worry" is simply irresponsible.  You have nothing to lose if you're wrong, but the same is not true for Michael.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if the Home Office alleges deception, the only evidence Michael will be able to offer is his word, and the Home Office has too much experience with genuinely deceptive applicants to trust anyone's word.  The best evidence Michael can possibly have that the omission was unintentional will be his taking immediate action to correct the omission once it comes to his attention.  Only if he does that will he be able to protect himself against a possible finding of deception.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no such clauses in the forms for most countries. Form says to "answer truthfully", even an inadvertent lie is considered a lie. Just because you didn't know when completing the application doesn't excempt you from having had to know, you should have done your research more thoroughly.

Comment: @phoog: it is not about *immoral* or *unethical*, but about law. In any case, I'm curious on how would you write to FO. "Here the corrected form, the previous one was wrong" (but I signed it, so my signature is not trustfully), or "I discovered in a small talk with my family an error" (so I'm totally misinformed, do not trust me), or what? By done nothing, you have the "I never got a visa refusal: my parents applied for me unknowingly, and it seems my parents received a refusal". So you will not blame yourself, but a reasonable error with complexity of law (and I doubt it is an error.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I’ve received my visa without any update needed. Nonetheless, I would advise closer attention be paid when filling application forms to mitigate against anxiety.

Comment: Congratulations, but please remember that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site. The best "thank you" you can provide is to accept the answer that was most useful to you.

Answer (score 18):

**Yes, you definitely should update your application.**

Contact UKVI using [the link Traveller gave you](https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/prepare-your-application), with an explanation of what happened. You may possibly be refused a visa, but giving false information on a visa application - intentional or not - can be considered deception and might get you a ban. UK visa authorities can pull up your records and so will know about your refusal. Your explanation seems reasonable to me, and even at age 14 the refusal is not going to weigh very heavily against you.

Comment: As a minor, did *he* apply for a visa and was denied, or did his legal guardians do it for him?

Comment: My legal guardians applied for the visa on my behalf.

Comment: "depending on how young you were at the time of the refusal" -- OP explicitly provides this info (he was 14), so it should be possible for your answer to address this specifically rather than just say "depending".

Comment: @o.m. It doesn't matter.  Regardless of who was legally responsible for the visa application, Michael was refused a visa.  When asked "have you ever been refused a visa," he must answer in the affirmative.

Comment: @Michael I confirm phoog is correct

Comment: @o.m. irrelevant. The denial was on his/her application, therefore counts against him/her. Who filed the application is irrelevant in this regard. It's no different from when you let a commercial agent handle the paperwork and they file something in error. To the authorities you're responsible, only exception to that is if you decide to try to take legal action to recover the cost of the failed application from the agent.

Comment: While it was you who had a Visa refused, andvuou need to report it, that doesn't mean you will necessarily be held responsible for the contents of the previous application to the same extent as if you had made it as an adult.